# how to fix Git push behind remote counterpart

Tags: git

In Git, master branch changes should be integrated into dev branch. I made a copy of DEV first in local disk, then rebase master into DEV branch. then use WinMerge to manual compare file.

but looks like this strategy is not working. I did some search, one of solution is to use push 'force' to fix it. Do we have other elegant way ?

here are my steps:

```
aa@lenovo-pc MINGW64 /c/temp/TestGit2App (DevelopmentBranch)
$ git rebase -Xours master #keep the master changes first
# use WinMerge to merge changes back to files ...
git add -A
git commit -m "ddd"
git push

To 192.168.1.8:/home/git/TestGit2App.git
 ! [rejected]        DevelopmentBranch -> DevelopmentBranch (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@192.168.1.8:/home/git/TestGit2App.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Needing to force push your development branch to the remote, thereby overwriting the version previously there, is a completely normal part of the rebase workflow you are using.  When you rebased your development branch on master you *rewrote* the history of that former branch.  Consider the following simple diagram, where both the `dev` and `master` branches have each diverged by one commit each:

```
master: A -- B
dev:    A -- C
```

when you did this

```
git checkout dev
git rebase master
```

you ended up with this diagram

```
master: A -- B
dev:    A -- B -- C'
```

In other words, you pulled in the changes from `master` and then recommitted all your unique work on top of those changes.  If you look closely, you'll notice that the `C'` commit has an apostrophe.  This is to indicate that it is a completely different commit from the original `C` commit in your `dev` branch.

A side effect of your rebase is that the `dev` branch can no longer simply be pushed to the remote because the base has changed.  Instead, you will have to force push it via:

```
git push --force origin dev
```

Comment: thanks. but I used -Xours to discard all of my local changes first .

Comment: @user1615666 You are missing the point.  You rewrote the history of your dev branch and now you _must_ force push to the remote, or push it to a branch of some other name.

Comment: @user1615666 ...and there is nothing wrong with this.  Typically, you would only rebase right before the dev branch is ready to go back to master, so there is no concern if, e.g., you were sharing dev with some other developer.

Answer (score 0):

In short how you managed the conflict you are going to have to force push.  I don't like force pushing because it means some where along the way you didn't approach the merge correctly.

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging

I would have merged the specific commit/branch you changed by checking out master and merging that branch.  That is the great part of git you don't have to resolve the head you can resolve a branch to a specific branch.  It sounds like you resolved the head then replayed which is creating an order conflict by manually changing that commit.

Also you could also just stash your local changes and merge the master changes that pop your local changes back on which makes life so much easier.

Comment: I agree that force pushing is something which should not be taken lightly, but rebasing a feature branch before creating a pull request is one instance where force pushing is acceptable, if not totally needed.

Comment: That just seems counter intuitive,  I know some people like to use master for production then update master with a hotfix but then they need to go back and fix the feature branch and fix dev from the feature branch not master otherwise the commit history gets ass backwards.